# Why are 2 sets of separate QRadioButtons conflicting with each other?

Tags: pyqt5, qradiobutton

I’m trying to use 2 sets of QRadioButton(s) that select different attributes.

The snippet of the code reads:

```
self.imum_box = QHBoxLayout()
pigmemti_box = QHBoxLayout() # First set of QRadioButtons for attribute ‘Font color’ 
self.nuntium_1 = QLabel("Font color")
pigmemti_box.addWidget(self.nuntium_1)
self.t_albinus = QRadioButton("White",self)
self.t_albinus.setChecked(True)
self.t_albinus.toggled.connect(self.pigmemtum_has_changed)
self.t_nigreos = QRadioButton("Black",self)
self.t_nigreos.toggled.connect(self.pigmemtum_has_changed)
pigmemti_box.addWidget(self.t_albinus)
pigmemti_box.addWidget(self.t_nigreos)
self.etiqueta = QLabel("   ")
pigmemti_box.addWidget(self.etiqueta)
palette_box = QHBoxLayout() # Second set of QRadioButtons for attribute ‘Color palette’
self.nuntium_2 = QLabel("Color palette")
palette_box.addWidget(self.nuntium_2)
self.red_blue = QRadioButton("Blue and red",self)
self.red_blue.setChecked(True)
self.red_blue.toggled.connect(self.palette_has_changed)
palette_box.addWidget(self.red_blue)
self.echo_tops = QRadioButton("Echo tops",self)
self.echo_tops.setChecked(False)
self.echo_tops.toggled.connect(self.palette_has_changed)
palette_box.addWidget(self.echo_tops)
self.black_white = QRadioButton("Black and white",self)
self.black_white.setChecked(False)
self.black_white.toggled.connect(self.palette_has_changed)
palette_box.addWidget(self.black_white)
self.imum_box.addLayout(pigmemti_box)
self.imum_box.addLayout(palette_box)
self.tab1.setLayout(self.imum_box)  # This line just adds the 2 set to the general layout
```

The problem is that even though the QRadioButton(s) belong to different sets (and different layouts), they are still interfering. For example, if I check on ‘White’ , it will uncheck ‘Blue and red’ even though they are not supposed to be connected. The same problem happens if I check ‘Echo tops’ as it will uncheck ‘White’ or ‘Black.’ Not sure why this behavior.

Addendum: I also tried QButtonGroup with the following snippet:

```
self.imum_box = QHBoxLayout()
classis_pigmemti = QButtonGroup()
pigmemti_box = QHBoxLayout()
self.nuntium_1 = QLabel("Font color")
pigmemti_box.addWidget(self.nuntium_1)
self.t_albinus = QRadioButton("White",self)
self.t_albinus.setChecked(True)
self.t_nigreos = QRadioButton("Black",self)
pigmemti_box.addWidget(self.t_albinus)
pigmemti_box.addWidget(self.t_nigreos)
classis_pigmemti.addButton(self.t_albinus)
classis_pigmemti.addButton(self.t_nigreos)
palette_box = QHBoxLayout()
classis_palette = QButtonGroup()
self.nuntium_2 = QLabel("Color palette")
palette_box.addWidget(self.nuntium_2)
self.red_blue = QRadioButton("Blue and red",self)
self.red_blue.setChecked(True)
palette_box.addWidget(self.red_blue)
self.echo_tops = QRadioButton("Echo tops",self)
self.echo_tops.setChecked(False)
palette_box.addWidget(self.echo_tops)
self.black_white = QRadioButton("Black and white",self)
self.black_white.setChecked(False)
palette_box.addWidget(self.black_white)
classis_palette.addButton(self.red_blue)
classis_palette.addButton(self.echo_tops)
classis_palette.addButton(self.black_white)
self.imum_box.addLayout(pigmemti_box)
self.imum_box.addLayout(palette_box)
self.tab1.setLayout(self.imum_box)
```

However, this didn’t work either as it is possible to select 2 elements from the same set with none from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qradiobutton.html#details) state that by default all radiobuttons that belong to the same parent widget behave like one group. All your buttons have the same parent: `self`. Putting the buttons in different layouts has no influence on this.

If you want your "sets" to be independent of eachother, you should put them in separate [QButtonGroups](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbuttongroup.html)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        group_1 = QButtonGroup(self)
        group_2 = QButtonGroup(self)

        rb_1 = QRadioButton("1-a")
        rb_2 = QRadioButton("1-b")
        rb_3 = QRadioButton("2-a")
        rb_4 = QRadioButton("2-b")

        rb_1.setChecked(True)
        rb_3.setChecked(True)

        group_1.addButton(rb_1)
        group_1.addButton(rb_2)
        group_2.addButton(rb_3)
        group_2.addButton(rb_4)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(rb_1, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(rb_2, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(rb_3, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(rb_4, 1, 1)

app = QApplication([])
w = Test()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: I also tried using QButtonGroup but it didn't function properly either. The behavior was even worse because I could select 2 from the same set with none of the other. Let me add that snippet to the original question for further clarification.

Comment: I added the other snippet.

Comment: Set a parent (`self`) for the buttongroups.